# Microcontroller States

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, resistors, gpio

I'm using this [S23K142](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) Microcontroller - 64 pins.

I just want to know (in general as well as with respect to this microcontroller) how many states does this Microcontroller have?

By states I mean, Reset State, Default State, Normal State, During Reset State, After Reset state and Sleep state?

My questions:

1. I'm asking because I need to configure my Microcontroller (SPI, IC Communication, ADC & GPIO peripherals) pins , right? So, each of those pins would need to be configured differently during Reset, Sleep and default state right. So, how many states are there in the Microcontroller and where to view this information?
2. In general, Does Before Reset, After Reset and Reset - denote the same state? And does Default and normal pin configuration also mean the same? - Just trying to fix my terminology here.

Request you to help with the above 2 questions.

Comment: Have you read the manufacturer's datasheet?

Comment: Yes, I have read. Though I have not fully understood

Comment: I am not familiar with this micro but in general after reset or power-up the pin states are defined as input so they shows high impedance to outer system (doesnt affect it). If you need something else you must do it with external logic/resistors. Once the micro sucesfully booted you can change pin state in code.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet (with just 100 pages) is indeed not enough to obtain the details you need.

You saw that sections 4.6 and 4.7 list general information regarding all operating modes and you also find short notes across other sections (e.g. "should be off during transition").

Search for "S32K1xx MCU Family - Reference Manual" (sorry, could not find a precise link since it requires registration, try [this](https://www.nxp.com/webapp/Download?colCode=S32K1XXRM)). There you have 2179 pages which provide the details you need for the peripherals and mode transitions.

There is still information spread throughout the document, but you can get the fundamentals in:

[image]

[...]

[image]

> I just want to know [..] how many states does this Microcontroller have?
> By states I mean, Reset State, Default State, Normal State, During Reset State, After Reset state and Sleep state?

From the global picture given in this chapter you can understand the specifics for each peripheral: SPI, IC Communication, ADC & GPIO etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Upon seeing the reference manual, Table 39.1, page 1142, we can see there are 2 operating modes : Run and deep sleep. So, am I correct to assume that for each of the two modes, I can completely configure my IO pins of the microcontroller differently? Like, can I use a pin to be ADC input during Run mode and can I put the same pin as GPO during deep sleep mode? Am I correct in assuming so?